# Adding only new objects with cascade?

Tags: sqlalchemy, relationship, cascade

I wonder wether it's possible to add only new Child-Objects into a database when using a Parent-Child relationship. That is, when you add a Parent, the cascade should automatically only add those (new) children which are not in the Database rigth now, i.e. persistent. Can you override a childrens add-method to check this condition or is there any conventient workaround for this?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use [`Events`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.AttributeEvents) for the adding object. Just create one listener for the append event or create event and track your data. You can filter the date on that bases.

You can use the code like

```
from sqlalchemy import event

def child_append_listener(target, value, initiator):
    print "received append event for target: %s" % target

event.listen(Parent.children, 'append', child_append_listener)
```